# Issues with global context with react

Tags: next.js, react-context

I'm building an app with nextjs 13, react. I have a list of items that is displayed, and clicking on one is correctly being logged in the console as "Item clicked" but then the  can't seem to pass the state from my SelectableItems.js to the context (SelectedItemContext.js). The App.tsx is located in the /pages, I've tried it as _app and both .js and .tsx configurations. I've checked the descendants of the items in the return statement and it should work.

Basically I can click on the list in the html window, have the onClick register the item's name, but not pass information globally. It will update the information locally. I'm pretty amateur with this stuff, and I initially tried with redux but then have backtracked to trying just this, but even the simple set up here eludes me!

Any insights appreciated.

```js
// SelectableItems.js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelectedItem } from './SelectedItemContext';

const SelectableItem = ({ name }) => {
    const { selectedItem, setSelectedItem } = useSelectedItem();

    const handleClick = () => {
        const newItem = name === selectedItem ? null : name;
        setSelectedItem(newItem);

        console.log(`Item clicked: ${name}. New selected item: ${newItem}`);
    };

    return (
        <div
            className={`selectable-item ${name === selectedItem ? 'selected' : ''}`}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            {name}
        </div>
    );
};

export default SelectableItem;
```

```js
// App.tsx

import React from 'react';
import Header from '../app/page_items/zones/header';
// import { MainComponent } from '../app/page_items/lists/ListParser'
// import SelectableItem from '../app/page_items/lists/selecteditem/SelectableItems'
import { SelectedItemProvider } from '../app/page_items/lists/selecteditem/SelectedItemContext';
import Content from '../app/layout'

function App() {
    const [databaseName, setDatabaseName] = useState("");
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

    return (
        <SelectedItemProvider>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Content />
            </div>
        </SelectedItemProvider>
    );
};
```

```js
// SelectedItemContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
console.log("SelectedItemProvider loading!");

const SelectedItemContext = createContext({ selectedItem: null, setSelectedItem: () => { console.log('Default setSelectedItem invoked'); } });

export const useSelectedItem = () => {
    const context = useContext(SelectedItemContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useSelectedItem must be used within a SelectedItemProvider");
    }
    return context;
};

export const SelectedItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("SelectedItemProvider Mounted/Updated");
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Updated selectedItem:", selectedItem);
    }, [selectedItem]); // This hook runs every time selectedItem changes

    return (
        <SelectedItemContext.Provider value={{ selectedItem, setSelectedItem }}>
            {children}
            <div>Is this provider even rendering?</div>
        </SelectedItemContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SelectedItemContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly see anything wrong with how you made the context. However, I use next 13 with context and my file structure is not the same as yours. My guess is if your using next 13 you should have a `layout.tsx` file. In that file you should add your provider like this:

```js
import "@/app/globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { SelectedItemProvider } from '@/app/page_items/lists/selecteditem/SelectedItemContext';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/net.ico" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <SelectedItemProvider>
          {children}
        </SelectedItemProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, when you try to navigate to other pages, there will be a problem because the state will revert to the initial state, which is null. So you should use localStorage or something to cache the state.

Comment: Thank you! @Martini - that was so helpful! It took ten seconds to get it working after so damned long trying to figure it out, I just had to wrap the layout page in that SelectedItemProvider context and done!